# Simplifying (A+B)* C doesn't work

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This is simple, but it doesn't work:

```
In[1]=FullSimplify[(A0 + B0) C0]
Out[1]=(A0 + B0) C0
```

which should be:

```
A0 C0+ B0 C0
```

It doesn't work, Why?

Comment: `Expand[(A0 + B0) C0]` gives `A0 C0 + B0 C0` Simplify works by finding the "smallest" expression (in terms of leaf counting). So it sees `(A0 + B0) C0` as simpler, that is why.

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate of one that exhibited the same issue.  Please read that question and its answers, and if you feel it does not adequately address your question let me know.